# Momentum Equation VS Momentum of Momentum Equation

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, angular-momentum, momentum

Newton's second law states that  the linear momentum ($P$) rate is equal to the net force:
$$F=\frac{d}{dt}P \tag{1} $$ 
On the other side, there is a same expression for angular momentum ($L$):
$$M=\frac{d}{dt} \tag{2}L$$

In some books, the second equation is derived as a result of the first equation, but in some others, the second equation expressed as a principle or physical law, that is independent to the newton's second law.

My question is which one of these two approach is correct?

The moment of momentum equation is a result of newton's second law or it is an independent principle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two laws are the same.

To see this break down your rotating object into a sum of point masses. Then consider one of these masses:

[image: Point mass]

The angular momentum of our point mass is given by:

$$ L = rmv $$

so:

$$ \frac{dL}{dt} = \frac{d}{dt}(rmv) $$

For circular motion $r$ is constant so we get:

$$ \frac{dL}{dt} = rm\frac{dv}{dt} = rma $$

But the second law tells us that $ma$ is the just the applied force $F$, so we get:

$$ \frac{dL}{dt} = rF $$

and this is just the definition of torque so:

$$ \frac{dL}{dt} = T $$

To reconstruct our macroscopic object we now need to add up all our point masses. The total angular momemtum is just the sum of all the point mass angular momenta, and the total torque is just the sum of all the point mass torques, so our equation applies to the macroscopic body as well.

Answer (score 1):

Since it can be derived from the first equation, it's not an independent principle. In fact, you don't really need an angular momentum to make physical predictions. It's just useful to have. I remember when I programmed some elastic bodies simulation - particles connected with springs. I only implemented Newton's laws and equation for the spring. When I ran the simulation, all the "other" behaviour apperared emergently - conservation of momentum, moments of inertia etc.